# Sharing Ubuntu with Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

I want to make a virtual machine of ubuntu on sun virtualbox and share with my friends. It is for educational purposes. I can do it??

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by sharing? The given answers will differ if you'd like to share your disk, a service or access to the whole VM, or give a copy of it.

Comment: My answers to these questions may be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/95616/portable-virtual-machine and http://askubuntu.com/questions/287867/how-do-i-copy-to-dvd-my-virtualbox-windows-data

Comment: Do you mean (1) Is this technically possible to do? (2) Am I legally allowed to do this? Further you need to define more precisely what 'this' is as per lgarzo's comment.

Answer (score 0):

As per Ubuntu License yes, you may copy and distribute the machine to anyone you wish.  Just install, configure and export as a `OVA` file, for better compatibility.